# Functionaljava compilation errors

Tags: java, functional-java

From here: http://functionaljava.googlecode.com/svn/artifacts/3.0/demo/bgga/Option_filter.java

Q: Ho would I compile this example?
   If no way: What the purpose to put now working examples?

```
import fj.data.Option;
import static fj.data.Option.none;
import static fj.data.Option.some;
import static fj.Show.intShow;
import static fj.Show.optionShow;

public final class Option_filter {
  public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final Option<Integer> o1 = some(7);
    final Option<Integer> o2 = none();
    final Option<Integer> o3 = some(8);
    final Option<Integer> p1 = o1.filter({int i => i % 2 == 0});
    final Option<Integer> p2 = o2.filter({int i => i % 2 == 0});
    final Option<Integer> p3 = o3.filter({int i => i % 2 == 0});
    optionShow(intShow).println(p1); // None
    optionShow(intShow).println(p2); // None
    optionShow(intShow).println(p3); // Some(8)
  }
}
```

I don't see any chance for Java (5-7) compile this, for example:

```
filter({int i => i % 2 == 0});
```

Comment: Indeed, it doesn't compile in Java 7 (or earlier).  I imagine this is what you're looking for: https://code.google.com/p/functionaljava/source/browse/artifacts/3.0/demo/1.5/Option_filter.java.

Answer (score 1):

This example uses the proposed BGGA syntax.  Java 8 code examples are at http://www.functionaljava.org/examples-java8.html.  Your specific example is there and in the Github repo at https://github.com/functionaljava/functionaljava/blob/master/demo/src/main/java/fj/demo/Option_filter.java.

Your code is from the old repo and website.  Please use the new site at www.functionaljava.org and at github on github.com/functionaljava/functionaljava.